# Subtract 1 SQL from another

Tags: sql, oracle, difference

I would like to get the difference from two different SQL's.
I have seen similar questions but can't get them to verify.
Oracle.
here is my resolution with help from below;

```
select 
(TRUNC( "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."CREATE_TMSTMP" ) - NUMTODSINTERVAL( EXTRACT( DAY FROM TRUNC( "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."CREATE_TMSTMP" ) ), 'DAY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '1' MONTH - INTERVAL '1' DAY) "Month1",
sum(case when "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."EVENT_CD"='DSP_SUBMITTED' 
                and "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."DCN" IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1
                WHEN "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."EVENT_CD" ! ='DSP_SUBMITTED' 
                and "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."DCN" IS NOT NULL
                THEN -1
                 ELSE 0
           END)                "DCN"
 from 
"CJIMRPT"."V_EVENT_LOG_ENDTIME" "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE", 
"CJIMRPT"."V_REMAND" "C__en_zw__V_REMAND"
 where "C__en_zw__V_REMAND"."DCN"<>"C__en_zw__V_REMAND"."DOC_ID" and 
"C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."EVENT_CD"in('DSP_SUBMITTED','CPIC_PUBLISHING', 'DSP_PUBLISHED', 'DSP_PURGED', 'DSP_ARCHIVED', 'DSP_REJECTED', 'DSP_IDENT_ONLY') and 
not "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."DCN" is null and 
"C__en_zw__V_REMAND"."REMAND_ID"="C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."REMAND_ID" and 
"C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."CREATE_TMSTMP">=CASE WHEN EXTRACT( DAY FROM (TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - NUMTODSINTERVAL( EXTRACT( DAY FROM TRUNC( SYSDATE ) ), 'DAY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY) - NUMTODSINTERVAL( EXTRACT( DAY FROM (TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - NUMTODSINTERVAL( EXTRACT( DAY FROM TRUNC( SYSDATE ) ), 'DAY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY) ), 'DAY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY + NUMTOYMINTERVAL( -4, 'MONTH' ) + INTERVAL '1' MONTH - INTERVAL '1' DAY ) < EXTRACT( DAY FROM (TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - NUMTODSINTERVAL( EXTRACT( DAY FROM TRUNC( SYSDATE ) ), 'DAY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY) ) THEN (TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - NUMTODSINTERVAL( EXTRACT( DAY FROM TRUNC( SYSDATE ) ), 'DAY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY) - NUMTODSINTERVAL( EXTRACT( DAY FROM (TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - NUMTODSINTERVAL( EXTRACT( DAY FROM TRUNC( SYSDATE ) ), 'DAY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY) ), 'DAY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY + NUMTOYMINTERVAL( -4, 'MONTH' ) + INTERVAL '1' MONTH - INTERVAL '1' DAY ELSE (TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - NUMTODSINTERVAL( EXTRACT( DAY FROM TRUNC( SYSDATE ) ), 'DAY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY) + NUMTOYMINTERVAL( -4, 'MONTH' ) END and 
"C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."CREATE_TMSTMP"<(TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - NUMTODSINTERVAL( EXTRACT( DAY FROM TRUNC( SYSDATE ) ), 'DAY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
group by (TRUNC( "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."CREATE_TMSTMP" ) - NUMTODSINTERVAL( EXTRACT( DAY FROM TRUNC( "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."CREATE_TMSTMP" ) ), 'DAY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '1' MONTH - INTERVAL '1' DAY)
```

Comment: the only difference is the where clause

Comment: What didn't verify? What error did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it looks like the only difference between your two queries is the event_cd's being considered, you can simplify this into one query that grabs all of the event_cds that you have identified, and then sum 1 for the 'DSP_SUBMITTED' rows (your top query) and -1 for the other event_Cds (your bottom query).

I use a CASE that checks both the EVENT_CD to see if this is an up-count or a down-count, and also to check that "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."DCN" IS NOT NULL because your given logic of COUNT(DCN) does not count null values, so I need to replicate that behaviour.

```
select sum(case when "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."EVENT_CD"='DSP_SUBMITTED' 
                and "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."DCN" IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1
                WHEN "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."EVENT_CD" ! ='DSP_SUBMITTED' 
                and "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."DCN" IS NOT NULL
                THEN -1
                 ELSE 0
           END)                "DCN"
 from 
"CJIMRPT"."V_EVENT_LOG_ENDTIME" "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE", 
"CJIMRPT"."V_REMAND" "C__en_zw__V_REMAND"
 where "C__en_zw__V_REMAND"."DCN"<>"C__en_zw__V_REMAND"."DOC_ID" and 
"C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."EVENT_CD"in('DSP_SUBMITTED','CPIC_PUBLISHING', 'DSP_PUBLISHED', 'DSP_PURGED', 'DSP_ARCHIVED', 'DSP_REJECTED', 'DSP_IDENT_ONLY') and 
not "C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."DCN" is null and 
"C__en_zw__V_REMAND"."REMAND_ID"="C__en_zw__V_EVENT_LOG_ENDDATE"."REMAND_ID"
```

Comment: thanks guys, I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: The following SQL does what I want, Thanks to all for the input.

Comment: Unfortunately the SQL is too long to put in, unless someone has a better way. new to the website.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is not related to the `MINUS` operator but you want a substraction result of the count of records from two queries, if I am understanding correctly. Which can be depicted as simple as below-

```
select (select count(*) from dual) - (select count(*) from dual)
 from dual;
```

You will need to replace the `select count(*) from dual` with your own `count(*)` queries.

Beware, if you apply the `MINUS` operator first, as @kevinsky says in his answer, **and then** do a `count(*)` your result may not be desirable or expected (illustrated by examples below)-

```
 select count(*)
 from (
         select * from  (select 1 from dual
                             union
                             select 2 from dual
                             union
                             select 3 from dual
                             union
                             select 4 from dual)
         minus
          select * from (select 1 from dual
                              union
                             select 2 from dual
                             union
                             select 5 from dual
                             union
                             select 6 from dual));
 --Retruns result as 2

 select (select count(*)
                   from  (select 1 from dual
                             union
                             select 2 from dual
                             union
                             select 3 from dual
                             union
                             select 4 from dual))
         -
        (select count(*)
                   from (select 1 from dual
                              union
                             select 2 from dual
                             union
                             select 5 from dual
                             union
                             select 6 from dual)) cnt
 from dual;     
--Returns result as 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [MINUS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) operator to subtract one set of records from another or INTERSECT to find the common elements.  The two sets must have the same number of columns.
Just replace the - with MINUS keyword.

Oracle's example

```
SELECT product_id FROM inventories
MINUS
SELECT product_id FROM order_items;
```

Comment: This minus function works. however, to simplify the SQL for the example I removed the monthly breakdown. Unfortunately when the month is added back in the MINUS function does not work. I will try the nested select above.